# How to connect to mysql with laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, localhost

This is such a simple basic question I don't think many people are asking this but simply how do I connect to MySQL through localhost phpmyadmin with Laravel (I've searched, and there is some stuff, but I need to ask because I am a noob and I'd like to ask, the stuff I saw I don't quite get 100% or I tried and it didn't help)?

I am working with [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) and am brand new to [laravel](https://laravel.com/), I installed [laravel](https://laravel.com/) inside `C:\wamp\www\laravel-project`

I tried

```
c:\wamp\www\laravel-project> php artisan migrate:make create_tasks_table --table tasks --create
```

And

```
c:\wamp\www\laravel-project> php artisan migrate
```

I expect to have to define the database information, I checked `C:\wamp\www\laravel-project\app\config\database.php` and it looks correct, mySQL is set on the defaults `root` being the user name, and '' empty being the password.

The error in the command line I get after running `php artisan migrate` is

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'database'
```

I am using Windows 8, and Wamp for my localhost server, it of course includes phpmyadmin and mySql. So I am sure there are tons of ways to use MySQL but I don't think I am setting up [laravel](https://laravel.com/) and phpmyadmin properly.

So any insight would be amazing, easy points.

**EDIT:**

Thinking this through maybe I need to create a database named `database` Let me try that. be back soon. Okay, I'll answer my question or someone can, just in case someone searches this topic... it is **KEY** to make sure the database defined in `C:\wamp\www\laravel-project\app\config\database.php` matches a database that exists inside your phpmyadmin. No brainer!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database the standards docs I think are useful here

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Laravel makes it very easy to manage your database connections through `app/config/database.php`.

As you noted, it is looking for a database called 'database'. The reason being that this is the default name in the database configuration file.

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database', <------ Default name for database
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Change this to the name of the database that you would like to connect to like this:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'my_awesome_data', <------ change name for database
    'username'  => 'root',            <------ remember credentials
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Once you have this configured correctly you will easily be able to access your database!

Happy Coding!

Comment: helloo gerobk sir i have made some changes in this file but i am not able to connect

Comment: See below for the current 5.* version solution.

Comment: `app/config/database.php` is technically the right file, but in practice it often just pulls in `username` etc. values from the `.env` file..... The `.env` file is located in the laravel project's root folder, above both the `app` and `config` folders

Answer (score 86):

In Laravel 5, there is a `.env` file,

It looks like

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=YOUR_API_KEY

DB_HOST=YOUR_HOST
DB_DATABASE=YOUR_DATABASE
DB_USERNAME=YOUR_USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

Edit that .env There is .env.sample is there , try to create from that if no such .env file found.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer since Laravel 5!

Comment: The `.env` file is located in the laravel project's root folder, above both the `app` and `config` folders

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you forgot to first create a table migrations:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

Also there is a very userful package Generators, which makes a lot of work for you https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators#views

Answer (score 6):

It's also much more better to not modify the `app/config/database.php` file itself... otherwise modify `.env` file and put your DB info there. (`.env` file is available in Laravel 5, not sure if it was there in previous versions...)

**NOTE:** Of course you should have already set `mysql` as your default database connection in the `app/config/database.php` file.

Comment: I want to modify .env file to work with MYSQL, please give me example?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out. Finally, I tried shutting down my development server and booting it up again. Frustratingly, this worked for me. 
I came to the conclusion, that after editing the `.env` file in Laravel 5, you have to exit the server, and run `php artisan serve` again.

Answer (score 1):

You probably only forgot to create database. Enter your PHPMyAdmin and do it from there.

Edit: Definitely don't go with Maulik's answer. Not only it is using mysql_ extenstion (which is commonly recognized bad practice), Laravel is also taking care of your connections using PDO.