# Laravel not connected with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in the laravel also in stackoverflow, I tried to configure database in my laravel application. but it is not working and always shows error to me. here is my database.php file.

**database.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => 'mysql',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path().'/database.sqlite',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'horsi',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'horsi'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'horsi'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

I am also attaching my .env files

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=horsi
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

I also tried to configure my database like

```
'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'horsi'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

But it is not working, anyone can help me to get the solution

Error:  null in place of username and poassword

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz1Di.png)

Comment: What error does it show? If you're trying to connect to a DB using `localhost` as host and `root` without password with MySQL Workbench, for example, are you able to connect?

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Bad idea. Don't use mysql_. You using a framework with it's inner architecture. It uses PDO. Just check my answer.

Comment: Added image please check

Comment: what error it showing?

Comment: Hey please check this link if it does your work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208776/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this line

```
'default' => env('DB_DEFAULT', 'mysql')
```

instead place of

```
 'default' => 'mysql'
```

And set `DB_DEFAULT=mysql` in .env file

Comment: And in this case also need to add to `.env` file `DB_DEFAULT=mysql`

Answer (score 1):

You use default DB as `'default' => 'mysql'`

But `.env` configs are going for `pgsql` in your config file.

So if you're going to use MYSQL, set this

```
'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'horsi'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
```

for `mysql` section in your `config.php`