# HTTP Error 500 on Localhost when using Laravel Product Youtube Clone

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

So I purchased a Youtube Clone Script called StreamTube, and I have been attempting to host the code that has been given to me. However, whenever I try to run the index page, I always get:

**localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

I looked inside of the laravel.log file to try and figure out what was going wrong, and I get about 20 errors that all say roughly the same thing:

```
Unknown database 'streamtube' in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:55
```

While I now know that this is the error given, I am a little stumped as to where to proceed from here. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on where I could start looking for solutions.

So far I have confirmed all of my software requirements are up to date, and nothing seems to be wrong with any of the Laravel code itself, I guess I'm just wondering how one would go about finding an unknown database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: most likely you need to create the database

Comment: Do you have access to your database? Did the script require that you make additions to the database?

Comment: This seems to be more of a support request for your script vendor rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JayBlanchard none of your linked questions (duplicates) are related to the OPs problem. Please don't insta-close questions.

Comment: This addresses the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208776/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-laravel

Comment: Problem solved, you were all kind of right! I needed to actually make the database in php_myadmin. I was under the impression that it would come with the database, whoops. Thank you everyone.